# How to limit writable directory selection in NSOpenPanel?

Tags: macos, cocoa, directory, nsopenpanel

I want user to select a directory for files to save into. My simplest codes (ARC):

```
NSOpenPanel *panel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];

[panel setCanChooseDirectories:YES];
[panel setCanChooseFiles:NO];
[panel setAllowsMultipleSelection:NO];

if (NSOKButton == [panel runModal]) 
    return [[panel URLs] objectAtIndex:0];
else
    return nil;
```

However, I want to ensure the returned path **writeable** so that I can save files into it. How should I modify my codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement the `shouldEnableURL` delegate method as follows:

```
- (BOOL)panel:(id)sender shouldEnableURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    return [[NSFileManager defaultManager] isWritableFileAtPath:[url path]];
}
```

This will render all non-writable paths as unselectable in the open panel.
The object that acts as your panel delegate should conform to `NSOpenSavePanelDelegate`.
Don't forget to set it via:

```
[panel setDelegate:self];
```

Detailed information about the NSOpenSavePanelDelegate protocol [can be found in the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/NSOpenSavePanelDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Oh, `NSFileManager`... Thank you very much!

Comment: Opps! I thought it worked yesterday. But no. this method is "-isWritable **File** AtPath". But what I process with are directory urls and this always return "NO".

Comment: Oh, sorry, my fault. I call **[url isFileURL]** in previous, thinking that returns whether the URL is NOT a directory.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift you can limit particular types this way, by implementing shouldEnable url delegate method.

```
 func panel(_ sender: Any, shouldEnable url: URL) -> Bool {
        if String(url.pathExtension) == "pdf" {
            return false
        }
        return true
 }
```